# Choosing random value from weighted options in java

Tags: java, random

When the user clicks, a random output from a set of outputs must be selected. The chances for one value needs to be higher than the other. For example, you click a button and you either receive `Bronze`, `Silver`, `Gold`, or `Platinum`. Obviously, if you click randomly, you should receive Bronze more than Silver, more than Gold, more than Platinum. For example, could it maybe look like this:

```
printRandom("Bronze", 30, "Silver", 20, "Gold", 10, "Platinum", 5, "You didn't get anything.");
```

Where the final result is when you were unlucky enough to get none. I've been having trouble with making one option more common than the other, not choosing a value in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: The Apache Commons RNG library has classes for this.

Comment: Is 30 a weight or a percentage? If it's meant to be a weight then "You didn't get anything" is missing it's weight. Otherwise, are we to assume it's 35%?

Comment: I just put the numbers to signify how likely an option is. Since 30 is more than 20, 30 will be chosen more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, you could do the following:

```
int random = Math.random();

if (random < 0.05) { // 5/100
  return "Platinum";
} else if (random < 0.1) { // 10/100
  return "Gold";
} else if (random < 0.2) { // 20/100
  return "Silver";
} else if (random < 0.3) { // 30/100
  return "Bronze";
} else {
  return "You didn't get anything.";
}
```

Comment: The early returns eat into the likely hood of later returns. You'll get Platinum 5%, Gold 5%, Silver 10%, Bronze 10%. I don't think that is what was intended.

Comment: No, not really. I think I can fix this by instead setting a string value instead of returning it, so that there is a chance to overwrite the platinum / gold etc.